# Reload frame option from Chrome through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, reload

I want to use the "Reload frame" option from Google Chrome (and other browsers) in my script. After an action it needs to reload the frame but needs to reload the same page in the frame.

Is it possible to call this function/option from Chrome/Firefox/IE in Javascript/jQuery?

I added a picture just be clear:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/evrGu.jpg

Comment: just use `window.location.reload(true);` from within the frame

Comment: Doesn't work because I work with sessions in PHP.

Comment: @Bale what is wrong with `window.location.reload(true);` and PHP session? Maybe just `window.location.reload();`, not sure about that

Comment: If I use `window.location.reload();` i'm getting a white page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$('#iframe').attr('src', $('#iframe').attr('src'));
```

essentially it changes the src to itself, causing a new request to be made with the same address